# Testing Scala.JS + Play with ScalaTest and Selenium

Tags: playframework, scalatest, scala.js

I'm struggling with how to test my Play + Scala.JS project using Selenium and ScalaTest.  I have a fair amount of code running on the browser that interacts with the Play backend;  it seems like using Selenium would be a good way to test that everything works together correctly.

My current project is organized with the following modules:

```
xplatform          Scala code running on both JVM and JS
  ├── browser      Scala code running on the browser
  ├── server       Common code running on the (Play) server
        ├── wapp   Web app: controllers and such
        ├── wsvc   Web services:  controllers and such
```

The root module depends on and aggregates wapp, wsvc, and browser.

I've created a separate module (selTests) for the Selenium tests.  It depends on both wapp and wsvc.  I put the selenium tests in a separate module because if they are in the root module running `test-only selTests.MyTest` looks for it in all of the modules, which annoys me and slows everything down.  With it in a separate module I can `project selTests` and then `test-only ...` and just that test runs.

This is working fine on those pages that do not use Scala.JS code (ie: don't use the browser module) because it can't load `browser-jsdeps.js` and `browser-fastopt.js`.  You'll say, "Aha!  But you didn't make selTests depend on browser!".  If I do that, running a test produces the following error and hangs SBT:

```
[seleniumTests] $ test-only selTests.general.HomePageRootPermsSpec
[error] Uncaught exception when running tests: java.io.InvalidClassException: sbt.testing.TaskDef; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -7417691495999416204, local class serialVersionUID = 2663134200025980977
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last seleniumTests/test:testOnly for the full output.
^Cbelser:oat3 bwbecker$
```

If I move the tests to the root project it still doesn't find the `jsdeps.js` and `fastopt.js` resources.

I just found [scala-js/scala-js-env-selenium](https://github.com/scala-js/scala-js-env-selenium) but can't tell from the ReadMe what problem it's supposed to solve.

So... How do you use Selenium with ScalaTest to test a Play project that uses Scala.js?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly where the issue is for you, but if you'd like a functioning example, feel free to poke around the source code for  [Querki](https://www.querki.net/). Some relevant files:

- [build.sbt](https://github.com/jducoeur/Querki/blob/master/querki/build.sbt)
- [Functional (Selenium) tests](https://github.com/jducoeur/Querki/tree/master/querki/scalajvm/test/querki/test/functional), and specifically
- [Functional test root](https://github.com/jducoeur/Querki/blob/master/querki/scalajvm/test/querki/test/functional/QuerkiFuncTests.scala)

I wouldn't say it's the most elegant test code (I wrote it a couple of years ago, and there are some experiments I would do differently now), but it works as intended: it boots up Chrome, connects via Selenium and puts everything through their paces. It does *not* use scala-js-env-selenium (which is newer than this), but does use [ScalaTest+Play](http://www.scalatest.org/plus/play).